# I want to take out Last Digit of Huge Number Stored in BigInteger In JAVA

Tags: java, factorial

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LastFact
{
    // Returns Factorial of N
    static BigInteger factorial(int N)
    {
        // Initialize result
        BigInteger f = new BigInteger("1"); // Or BigInteger.ONE

        // Multiply f with 2, 3, ...N
        for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++)
            f = f.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));

        return f;
    }

    // Driver method
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        int N = 300;

        System.out.println(factorial(N));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice you put the code but You miss to ask a question here

Comment: something like the remainder if divided by `TEN` ? (assuming the question is how to get the last digit...) {Note: there is also a `BigInteger.ONE`}

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to take out the last digit and use it? Or divide the number by ten? Or make the last digit zero?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the last `N` digits of a `BigInteger` divide it by `10^N` e.g. to remove the last two digits divide by `10^2=100`:

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("123456");
BigInteger j = i.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(100)); // j=1234
```

To get the reminder that you are removing use the `reminder()` method instead:

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("123456");
BigInteger j = i.reminder(BigInteger.valueOf(100)); // j=56
```

Please note that since you are calculating large factorials you might want to use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Answer (score 1):

To take the last digit get the remainder of `BigInteger` when divided by 10

```
System.out.println(f.remainder(BigInteger.TEN));
```

Comment: Why BigDecimal?

Comment: Sorry, it was a quick mistake. I have edited it. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

Convert your big integer in to string then take last digit.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    int N = 300;

        String bigNumber = factorial(N).toString();
        String lastNumberStr = bigNumber.charAt(bigNumber.length()-1)+"";
        int lastNumber = Integer.parseInt(lastNumberStr);

        System.out.println(lastNumber);
}
```

Comment: when i put 4 as input  it should give me 4 as output as factorial of 4 is 24 and it should return 4 . but it is returning 52 .

Comment: @ukdev its fixed, i was returning ascii value of number

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function:

```
public byte lastDigit(BigInteger value) {
    String str = String.valueOf(value);
    String digit = str.substring(str.length() - 1, str.length());
    return Byte.valueOf(digit);
}
```